# Is there a way to specify a where condition for all tests in a model in DBT?

Tags: yaml, dbt

I would like to write some tests for my dbt model. I only want the tests to test certain rows (data within the last month). I could write a where clause for every single test in yml file like so:

```
          - not_null
          config:
            where: "current_date-date_column<=30"
```

However, I was wondering if there is some shortcut to put the clause on the model and have the where clause apply to all tests of the model (which is a lot easier to write and also means I don't have to worry about forgetting if I add more tests).

[This article](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/where) givers an example on how to do that for project level but I don't want the whole project just one model.

Answer (score 1):

Any config that can be applied in the `dbt_project.yml` can be scoped to specific directories or resources. However, tests are their own resources, independent of the models they test, and currently (dbt v1.2), it is not possible apply config to all tests for a given model.

As a workaround, you could consider putting the `.yml` file that defines the tests for that model in a directory by itself, and applying the config to a directory.

Apply `where` to a whole project:

```yaml
tests:
  +where: "date_column = current_date"
```

Apply `where` only to `.yml` files nested in the `models/marts/finance/` directory:

```yaml
tests:
  my_project:
    marts:
      finance:
        +where: "date_column = current_date"
```

Apply `where` to a specific test:

```yaml
tests:
  my_project:
    marts:
      finance:
        not_null_revenue_id:
          +where: "date_column = current_date"
```

See the docs for [resource-path](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/resource-path) for more info

Comment: It works only for  project level or folder level, but I can't drill down to an individual model for some reason.

Comment: if I do, I get this error: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
There are 1 unused configuration paths:
- tests.my_project.conformed.finance.my_model

Comment: Can confirm that. As a workaround, I moved the one model to a separate subfolder so now I'm able to specify that subfolder.

Comment: Interesting. I'd assumed that tests would be nested under their models, but they are their own resources, with their own resource paths, so my answer is wrong! I'll edit it, but I think today you are right that you can't apply config to all tests on a single model. This is strange to me -- I'd consider opening an issue in the dbt-core repo to request this feature